# InFix to Post Fix Converter

Tags: java

I have tried to change my code and debug it but I am always getting the wrong converter. Can anyone help show me where the error is?

```
public class Driver {
    static String postfix;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String me = "((5+6)*(7-8))";
        String a =changeFromInfixToPostfi(me);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static String changeFromInfixToPostfi(String s) {
        LinkedStack stack = new LinkedStack();
        String postfix = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
                postfix += s.charAt(i);
            else {
                postfix += ",";
                if (stack.isEmpty())
                    stack.Deposit(s.charAt(i));
                else {
                    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                        if (!checkstackTop(stack.MyPeek(), s.charAt(i) +"")) {
                            stack.Deposit(s.charAt(i));
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            postfix += stack.Withdraw() + ",";
                            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                                stack.Deposit(s.charAt(i));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while (!stack.isEmpty())
            postfix += "," + stack.Withdraw();
        return postfix;
    }

    public static boolean checkstackTop(Node top, String schar) {
        if ((top.equals("*") || top.equals("/"))
                && (schar.equals("+") || schar.equals("-")))
            return true;
        else if ((top.equals("+") || top.equals("-"))
                && (schar.equals("+") || schar.equals("-")))
            return true;
        else if (top.equals("(") && schar.equals(")"))
            return true;
        else if (top.equals("(") && schar.equals("("))
            return true;
        else if ((top.equals("*") || top.equals("/"))
                && (schar.equals("*") || schar.equals("/")))
            return true;
        else if ((top.equals("+") || top.equals("-") || top.equals("*") || top
                    .equals("/")) && schar.equals(")"))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: SO doesnt debug but can help.. what's the input and what's the output you get?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: input  :  ((5+6)*(7-8))
output : 5678-*+
the output should be 5 6 + 7 8 - *

Comment: Try this: stack.Deposit(s.charAt(i)) + " "; instead of stack.Deposit(s.charAt(i));

Comment: I don't think you can interpret or convert infix reading and processing 1 character at a time. For example: 5+5*3+5+4*5